# Group dates by week in R

Tags: r, date-arithmetic, week-number

I wish to label my data based on their week. This is my data:

```
df2 <- structure(list(Order_Date = structure(c(16735, 16805, 16753, 
16830, 17075, 17009, 17085, 16740, 16891, 16750, 16820, 16849, 
16906, 16929, 16746, 16731, 16786, 16873, 16895, 16931), class = "Date")), .Names = "Order_Date", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I tried to label them based on the week (0th week, 1th week and ....) and I wish to group my data by the week later

And I tried this:

```
# order by data
library (dplyr)
df2<- arrange(df2, Order_Date)


# label them by week
$df2$week <- cumsum(weekdays(df2$Order_Date) == "Friday")
```

It doesn't give me the correct result and I have the following output, which is weird

```
   Order_Date week
1  2015-10-27    0
2  2016-01-05    0
3  2015-11-14    0
4  2016-01-30    0
5  2016-10-01    0
6  2016-07-27    0
7  2016-10-11    0
8  2015-11-01    0
9  2016-03-31    0
10 2015-11-11    0
11 2016-01-20    0
12 2016-02-18    0
13 2016-04-15    1
14 2016-05-08    1
15 2015-11-07    1
16 2015-10-23    2
17 2015-12-17    2
18 2016-03-13    2
19 2016-04-04    2
20 2016-05-10    2
```

Ideally, I'd like to have this output:

```
  Order_Date   label
1  2015-10-23   0
2  2015-10-27   0
3  2015-11-01   1
4  2015-11-07   2
5  2015-11-11   2
6  2015-11-14   3
7  2015-12-17   8
8  2016-01-05   10
```

since row number 8 occurs 10 week after row number 1 but also a solution that generates the following is my second alternative that shows these data are not in the same week:

```
  Order_Date   label
1  2015-10-23   0
2  2015-10-27   0
3  2015-11-01   1
4  2015-11-07   2
5  2015-11-11   2
6  2015-11-14   3
7  2015-12-17   4
8  2016-01-05   5
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @akrun I update the question, please let me know if it is not still clear.

Comment: Why would you expect `cumsum(weekdays(df2$Order_Date) == "Friday")` to give you week-number? It will only tell you the cumulative number of dates in that column which happened to be Fridays (but they're unordered, and not every day or week is covered; what if you skip a Friday or two?). That has nothing to do with the week-number.

Comment: @smci that's correct, I hoped to at least find a solution to find the dates which are in the same week, Look at my alternative desirable output at the bottom of the question please.

Comment: Then use the week-of-year functions from either zoo or lubridate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code below calculates the current week relative to the minimum week in the data. `week2` uses modular arithmetic to make the code more concise, although the week numbers don't always line up exactly with the direct calculation of years and week numbers using `lubridate` functions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df2 %>% mutate(week = (year(Order_Date) - year(min(Order_Date)))*52 + 
                 week(Order_Date) - week(min(Order_Date)),
               week2 = (as.numeric(Order_Date) %/% 7) - (as.numeric(min(Order_Date)) %/% 7)) %>%
  arrange(Order_Date)
```

> ```
>    Order_Date week week2
> 1  2015-10-23    0     0
> 2  2015-10-27    0     0
> 3  2015-11-01    1     1
> 4  2015-11-07    2     2
> 5  2015-11-11    2     2
> 6  2015-11-14    3     3
> 7  2015-12-17    8     8
> 8  2016-01-05   10    10
> 9  2016-01-20   12    12
> 10 2016-01-30   14    14
> 11 2016-02-18   16    17
> 12 2016-03-13   20    20
> 13 2016-03-31   22    23
> 14 2016-04-04   23    23
> 15 2016-04-15   25    25
> 16 2016-05-08   28    28
> 17 2016-05-10   28    28
> 18 2016-07-27   39    39
> 19 2016-10-01   49    49
> 20 2016-10-11   50    50
> ```

Comment: I guess we can also use `week()` from `lubridate` package

Comment: I did use `week()` from the `lubridate` package.

Answer (score 10):

`cut.Date` takes an interval specification (see `?cut.Date`).

Your data covers a whole year, so unless you want to re-name those weeks, this will count up the actual number of weeks:

```r
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
  mutate(week = cut.Date(Order_Date, breaks = "1 week", labels = FALSE)) %>% 
  arrange(Order_Date)

#>    Order_Date week
#> 1  2015-10-23    1
#> 2  2015-10-27    2
#> 3  2015-11-01    2
#> 4  2015-11-07    3
#> 5  2015-11-11    4
#> 6  2015-11-14    4
#> 7  2015-12-17    9
#> 8  2016-01-05   12
#> 9  2016-01-20   14
#> 10 2016-01-30   15
#> 11 2016-02-18   18
#> 12 2016-03-13   21
#> 13 2016-03-31   24
#> 14 2016-04-04   25
#> 15 2016-04-15   26
#> 16 2016-05-08   29
#> 17 2016-05-10   30
#> 18 2016-07-27   41
#> 19 2016-10-01   50
#> 20 2016-10-11   52
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Both solution worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could use the ISOweek package to convert the dates to ISOweek format and then use that for filtering your output.

Example code using ISOweek package:

```
library(ISOweek)
x <- paste0(2000:2017, "-01-01")
x <- as.Date(x)
y <- ISOweek(x)
print(y)
```