# Loops in R, Looping a specific ISIN for multiple operations

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

For my bachelor project I conduct a performance analysis in R. Unfortunately I have no experience with loops and could not find any suitable solutions.

I got a dataframe with daily data which is divided into 3 different volumes/ sizes. For one stock I need about 2000 lines of code to analyze it on a weekly basis. In my dataframe there are about 99 shares in 3 different sizes, so I would have to copy/paste the ISIN number every time.

To get an impression here the code:

```
w01.2016_DE0005089031 <- df_DE0005089031 %>% 
  dplyr::select(Date, ClosingPrice ) %>%
  dplyr::filter(Date >= as.Date("2016-01-04") & Date <= as.Date("2016-01-10"))

w01.2016_DE0005089031 <- log((w01.2016_DE0005089031[ nrow(w01.2016_DE0005089031),2]) / w01.2016_DE0005089031[1,2])
.
.up to
.
w18.2020_DE0005089031 <- df_DE0005089031 %>% 
  dplyr::select(Date, ClosingPrice ) %>%
  dplyr::filter(Date >= as.Date("2020-04-27") & Date <= as.Date("2020-04-30"))

w18.2020_DE0005089031 <- log((w18.2020_DE0005089031[ nrow(w18.2020_DE0005089031),2]) / w18.2020_DE0005089031[1,2])
```

and

```
df01_w01_2016_SmallCap <- df %>%
  dplyr::select(Underlying, Date, Size, ClosingPrice, NumberOfBuyers, NumberOfSellers) %>%
  dplyr::filter(Underlying == "DE0005089031", Size == "SmallCap", Date >= as.Date("2016-01-04") & Date <= as.Date("2016-01-10"))
.
.up to
.
df01_w18_2020_SmallCap <- df %>%
  dplyr::select(Underlying, Date, Size, ClosingPrice, NumberOfBuyers, NumberOfSellers) %>%
  dplyr::filter(Underlying == "DE0005089031", Size == "SmallCap", Date >= as.Date("2019-04-27") & Date <= as.Date("2019-03-30"))
```

in addition there are various merges and analysis.

Is it possible to write a loop so that R does the same operation for the other 99 ISIN numbers (e.g. DE0005089031, DE000KGX8881, DE0006070006, etc...) without copy/paste and doing them all by hand?

I am thankful for any help. :)

Edit2:
my df looks like this:

```
Underlying       Date ClosingPrice      Size NumberOfBuyers NumberOfSellers
DE0005089031 04.01.2016      49.5010  SmallCap              0               0                    
DE0005089031 04.01.2016      49.5010 MediumCap              0               0                    
DE0005089031 04.01.2016      49.5010  LargeCap              1               2                    
DE0005089031 05.01.2016      49.7855  SmallCap              0               0                    
DE0005089031 05.01.2016      49.7855 MediumCap              0               1                    
DE0005089031 05.01.2016      49.7855  LargeCap              0               0 
.
.up to
.
 Underlying       Date ClosingPrice      Size NumberOfBuyers NumberOfSellers 
NL0012169213 29.04.2020        38.60 MediumCap              0               0                    
NL0012169213 29.04.2020        38.60  LargeCap              0               0                    
NL0012169213 29.04.2020        38.60  SmallCap              0               1                    
NL0012169213 30.04.2020        37.79 MediumCap              0               0                    
NL0012169213 30.04.2020        37.79  LargeCap              1               0                    
NL0012169213 30.04.2020        37.79  SmallCap              1               1
```

It has 412539 obs. of 7 variables with 99 shares

Comment: welcome to SO! in general, yes it's possible. However, it looks like you hardcoded your ISIN number into the name of the data.frame, which is not good style (because you can't easily automate analysis over several ISINs, it's easier to have it in one data.frame). Please give an example how your data looks like and a more detailed description what you want to do.

Comment: thank you! i edited the post with the df.

Comment: You can do the operation per underlying using `group_by(underlying)` .

Comment: Please don't post data as images. Take a look at [how to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to show data.

Comment: oh sorry. i edited. i will try it with a operation asap. thank you. ill keep you posted on how it went.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ronak Shah pointed out, you should take a look at `group_by` which groups your data according to a column (in your case `underlying`) and then the subsequent analysis is done. However, one can simplify also the first part of your analysis. You want your analysis done for every week, so first calculate the week (using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40581705/group-dates-by-week-in-r)) and then also group by `week`. With [`summarise`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html), you only get the result of your calculations. Try to get a better grip of what [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dplyr.html) can do.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data_raw <- "Underlying       Date ClosingPrice      Size NumberOfBuyers NumberOfSellers
DE0005089031 04.01.2016      49.5010  SmallCap              0               0                    
DE0005089031 04.01.2016      49.5010 MediumCap              0               0                    
DE0005089031 04.01.2016      49.5010  LargeCap              1               2                    
DE0005089031 05.01.2016      49.7855  SmallCap              0               0                    
DE0005089031 05.01.2016      49.7855 MediumCap              0               1                    
DE0005089031 05.01.2016      49.7855  LargeCap              0               0
DE0005089031 14.01.2016      49.5010  SmallCap              0               0                    
DE0005089031 14.01.2016      59.5010 MediumCap              0               0                    
DE0005089031 14.01.2016      69.5010  LargeCap              1               2                    
DE0005089031 15.01.2016      79.7855  SmallCap              0               0                    
DE0005089031 15.01.2016      89.7855 MediumCap              0               1                    
DE0005089031 15.01.2016      99.7855  LargeCap              0               0"

data <- read.table(text = data_raw, header = TRUE)

data %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y"),
         week = (year(Date) - year(min(Date)))*52 + 
           week(Date) - week(min(Date))) %>% 
  group_by(Underlying, week) %>% 
  summarise(calculation = log(ClosingPrice[1] / ClosingPrice[n()]))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Underlying [1]
  Underlying    week calculation
  <fct>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1 DE0005089031     0    -0.00573
2 DE0005089031     1    -0.339  
3 DE0005089031     2    -0.224
```

Comment: `# A tibble: 96 x 3
# Groups:   Underlying [96]
   Underlying    week calculation
   <fct>        <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 DE0005089031    NA      0.461 
 2 DE0005140008    NA      1.16  
 3 DE0005158703    NA     -0.380 
 4 DE0005190003    NA      0.555 
 5 DE0005200000    NA     -0.154 
 6 DE0005313704    NA     -1.18  
 7 DE0005408116    NA      0.653 
 8 DE0005419105    NA     -0.0399
 9 DE0005437305    NA     -0.728 
10 DE0005439004    NA      1.03  
# ... with 86 more rows` I get this result @starja. Unfortunately I get NAs and it changes I think directly the share.

Comment: The next question would be, if it works with groupby, can I calculate my correlations, betas and risk-free interest rates for each individual underlying in the same scheme? I use index data via yahoo finance in an extra dataframe.

Comment: It seems that the calculation of the week goes wrong. Have a look at this column and try to find out for which entries and why it goes wrong (entry is `NA`). In general, yes it is possible to calculate other things with this scheme, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50925734/dplyr-use-a-custom-function-in-summarize-after-group-by). Also, if you use `dplyr` in this way it's easier to have all data for the calculation in one data.frame